# How to index and query embedded attribute using Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, solrj

I'm new to Solr. I have such a requirement: index and query my main object which has **complex** attribute (a java object).

In hibernate search I can use `@IndexedEmbedded`, but I don't know how to do by using solr.

```
public class MyObject
{
    @org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field("attributes")
    private Set<Attribute> attributes = new HashSet<Attribute>();
....
}

public class Attribute {
        @org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field("attr_name")
        private String name;
        @org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field("attr_value")
        private String value;
.....
}
```

Now, I want to index the content of `MyObject` itself and also by it attributes. And I configue `schema.xml` like the following:

```
   <field name="attributes" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
   <field name="attr_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
   <field name="attr_value" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

When persit my object into db I use the following code to index in solr:

```
solrServer.addBean(myObj);
solrServer.commit();
```

But got error in solr server log:

```
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=691b6b57-4c14-498e-8298-db9c098f7b82] unknown field 'attributes'
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:340)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:115)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:157)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:79)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:58)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
```

I think because of my wrong configuration, can anybody correct me?

And I have a question of querying. I want to get `MyObject` by searching its attribute. Currently I search `MyObject` by the following code:

```
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setQuery(keyword);
    QueryResponse qr;
    List<MyObject> results=null;
    try {
        qr = solrServer.query(query);
        results = qr.getBeans(MyObject.class);
    } catch (SolrServerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I don't know how can I query by its attribute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should clarify what your requirements are. You can't have object with nested solrj annotations as far as I know, but even more important, you should think how your documents will look like while designing your schema. How about using some multivalued fields for example?

Comment: @Javanna Can't have object with nested solrj annotations? That's a bad news. I used to use hibernate search,I can use annotation of IndexedEmbedded to handle embeded object. I don't know how to achieve it in solrj

Comment: the main problem here is why you would need nested annotated objects. Your annotated object is a representation of your solr document, which is pretty simple: it basically has some fields, that's all. I'd have a look again at the definition of your schema, maybe you can clarify your requirements  within your question if you want more help.